# How to add Dyamic meta title for category in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.2, magento2.4

I want to set the meta title dynamically for the specific category. I am getting the meta title information based on the url id (?id = 1). How can i achieve this?

Any help can be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by the backend of magento
Login into admin, go to Catalog -> Categories, Select the category, open the collapse 'Search Engine Optimization' and set all meta data u want